# Sard's Theorem and a Submersion function from a product space

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, complex-geometry

Let $\Phi(x,y) \colon U_n \times U_M \to \mathbb{C}^n$ be a submersion, where $U_n \subset  \mathbb{C}^n$ and $U_M \subset \mathbb{C}^M$ are open sets with $M \geq n$.

1. Under which condition on $\Phi$ can I find some $s \in \mathbb{C}^M$ such that $\Phi( \cdot, s) \colon U_n \to \mathbb{C}^n$ is a submersion?
2. In that case, when is the set of such $s \in \mathbb{C}^M$ the complement of a set of measure zero?

Note that 1 is is not true in general. For example, take $f(x,y)=x^2-y$.

(For the second question I tried to use Sard's theorem, but I got a bit stuck...)

(Note that I asked the same question in Math Overflow, with no reply. So I thought it might be better to ask it here as well)

Comment: This is a sloppily written question. Are $U$ open sets? Is $M\ge n$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I edited the question to make it clearer.